# Parsing a variable in the array parameter not working with get_records_select

Tags: mysql, database, moodle

I need to get a list of the courses in moodle and count their respective sections as the number of topics and display in the form

`[{"id":"1","name":"mathematics","topic_count":"20"},
{"id":"3","name":"Geography","topic_count":"5"},].`

I tried the following

```
//initialize an array to hold the results
$result = array("id" =>0,"name" =>" ","topic_count" =>0);
$list  = "[";
$courses = $DB->get_records_sql("SELECT id,shortname FROM mdl_course WHERE id >?",array(1)) or die ("Error in executing query 1");
foreach ($courses as $course){
$id   = $course->id;
$null = "NULL";
$count = $DB->get_records_select("course_sections","course = ? AND name <> ?",array("course" =>$id, "name" => $null)) or die ("Error in executing query 2");
$result["id"]         = $course->id;
$result["name"]       = $course->shortname;
$result["topic_count"]= sizeof($count);
//append to list
$list .='{"id":"'.$result['id'].'","name":"'.$result['name'].'","topic_count":"'.$result['topic_count'].'"},';
}
$list .="]";
echo $list;
```

With this code I get the output

`"Error in executing query 2"`

But when instead of the $id I put a specific number say 2 I get the expected result with a constant count of sections (for course = 2 of course). Please help me out maybe I'm missing a very small point! I tried the `get_records_sql` but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an associative array for query 2

Either use

```
$count = $DB->get_records_select("course_sections","course = ? AND name <> ?",array($id, $null)) or die ("Error in executing query 2");
```

or

```
$count = $DB->get_records_select("course_sections","course = :course AND name <> :name",array("course" =>$id, "name" => $null)) or die ("Error in executing query 2");
```

UPDATE:

You can also use this to count the records

```
$DB->count_records_select('course_sections', "course = :course AND name <> :name",array("course" =>$id, "name" => $null));
```

http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API#Seeing_how_many_records_match_a_given_criterion

Comment: Thanks @Russel England, I tried that but the issue is it rejects whenever i use the variable '$id'. I can check that the id's are being pulled fine if I echo the '$id'.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you check for NULL values with 'IS NOT NULL', rather than '<> "NULL"'.

You might also find it a lot safer to generate an array of objects, then use the function 'json_encode' to generate the final output.

e.g.

```
$list = array();
foreach ($courses as $course) {
    $info = new stdClass();
    $info->id = $course->id;
    $info->name = $course->shortname;
    $info->topic_count = $DB->count_records_select('course_sections', 'course = ? AND name IS NOT NULL', array($course->id));
    $list[] = $info;
}
echo json_encode($list);
```

Comment: Note also - is query 1 supposed to give an error if no courses are found? That would normally be a valid condition, which just produces an empty array as the final output.

Comment: It looks like these functions do not want to accept a php variable. I can't get it to work. @davosmith

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are saying - which functions won't accept a PHP variable? Have you got debugging on for your site? What is the full error message you are getting?

Comment: whenever i parse $course->id or any variable to represent the id for the course the die. even with die(mysql_error()) nothing is displayed

Comment: Have you set debugging to developer for your site, and display debugging on? http://docs.moodle.org/en/Debugging/  That way you will get a better error message.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Apparently it is the 'or die()' statement which was troubling. Without it everything works just fine. All the suggested solutions work just fine in this case.

Answer (score 0):

try this code.
you can change the $condition as you want.
it helps.

```
global $DB;
$table = 'course';
$condition = 'visible= "1" AND  id!= "1" '; //is put into the where clause
$courses = $DB->get_records_select($table,$condition);
foreach($courses as $course){
echo '
'.$course->id.' '.userdate($course->startdate).'    '.$course->fullname.'   '.$course->summary.'
';
}
```